# How to use a class in another function

Tags: python, python-class

Fairly new to classes. I am trying to utilize a class to set a directory where the directory would then be used to access a file in a directory.

```
import json


class Dir:
    def __init__(self, dir):
        self.dir = dir


def get_currencyid(name, dir: Dir):
    with open(dir + 'currency.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    currencies = data.keys()
    for effect in currencies:
        if name in data[effect]['name']:
            id = data[effect]['id']
            return id


def get_all_currencies():
    with open('currency.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    effects = data.keys()
    for effect in effects:
        print("NAME:", data[effect]['name'], ": ID:", data[effect]['id'])


Dir(r"C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Firebot")

get_currencyid("Points")
```

So I want to set the directory then call the get_currency function which would use the directory passed in the Dir class.

Comment: In the context of your code, what is the benefit of this being a class? All you are storing here is a string. Just pass that arround if thats all you are doing with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "set the directory"? The point of a class is that it *represents a data type*. You don't "set" the directory; you *create an object* which *is* "the directory". From there, you pass it to your function the same way that you would pass anything else.

Comment: If you are "fairly new to classes" and don't understand how to do fundamental things with them, then you don't need Stack Overflow - you need a tutorial. Please understand that this is *not a discussion forum*.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understood it correctly, but here I tried my best to fix your code a little.

```
import json


class Dir:
    def __init__(self, dir):
        self.dir = dir


def get_currencyid(name, dir: Dir):
    with open(dir.dir + 'currency.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    currencies = data.keys()
    for effect in currencies:
        if name in data[effect]['name']:
            id = data[effect]['id']
            return id


def get_all_currencies():
    with open('currency.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    effects = data.keys()
    for effect in effects:
        print("NAME:", data[effect]['name'], ": ID:", data[effect]['id'])


directory = Dir(r"C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Firebot")

get_currencyid("Points", directory)
```

I created an instance of the class named directory. I passed the directory instance to the get_currencyid function. And then inside the get_currencyid function I changed the

```
with open(dir + 'currency.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

to

```
with open(dir.dir + 'currency.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

Because you need to access the "dir" instance variable inside of the class.

Comment: "get_currency_id" still looks dodgy to me:   depending on conditions, it either returns something or it doesn't; better to explicitly return None if the first return never occurs.

Comment: I thought it would return none automatically but you’re right. I’ll change that.